# SQL to search by associative items

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the below two tables and I need to be able to search by items to find the shopping_list_id.  Also, I want to limit the query so that it doesn't bring back other shopping lists with additional items on it.  Essentially, I'm checking to see if this is a shopping list the user has saved before.  The below query does NOT handle if there are shopping lists that match but with additional items, I'm stumped as to how to do that.

tables:

**shopping_list**

```
shopping_list_id
user
shopping_list_name
```

**shopping_list_item**

```
shopping_list_item_id
shopping_list_id
category_id
qty
qty_unit_id
```

This example has three items, but there could be any number.  My PHP code dynamically generates the SQL joins and where clause based on the user's input.

Query that I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sli.shopping_list_id 
FROM shopping_list_item sli 
JOIN shopping_list sl ON sli.shopping_list_id=sl.shopping_list_id 
JOIN shopping_list_item sli0 on sli.shopping_list_id=sli0.shopping_list_id 
JOIN shopping_list_item sli1 on sli.shopping_list_id=sli1.shopping_list_id 
JOIN shopping_list_item sli2 on sli.shopping_list_id=sli2.shopping_list_id 
WHERE sl.user_id=:webuser_id 
AND sli0.category_id=3 AND sli0.qty=1 AND sli0.qty_unit_id=3 
AND sli1.category_id=683 AND sli1.qty=1 AND sli1.qty_unit_id=3 
AND sli2.category_id=309 AND sli2.qty=1 AND sli2.qty_unit_id=7
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily with the `group by`/`having` approach to this type of query:

```
select sli.shopping_list_id
from shopping_list_item sli
group by sli.shopping_list_id
having sum(sli.category_id = 3 AND sli.qty = 1 AND sli.qty_unit_id) = 1 and
       sum(sli.category_id = 683 AND sli.qty = 1 AND sli.qty_unit_id = 3) = 1 and
       sum(sli.category_id = 309 AND sli.qty = 1 AND sli.qty_unit_id = 7) = 1 and
       count(*) = 3;
```